# How to lock a semaphore with multiple count

Tags: windows, synchronization, semaphore, waitforsingleobject

Semaphore is a counting object. The question is how to lock it with multiple count?

For example, I would like to call `lock(num, timeout)` function. It locks when there are at least `num` resources available, or fails when `timeout` passes, but there are still resources less than  `num` .

Is it possible on Windows? Or maybe using pthread?

Currently on Windows, `WaitForSingleObject` decreases the count of object by `1`. I think calling `WaitForSingleObject` multiple times cannot solve the problem because:

1. accurate timeout is hard to achieve and
2. I want to process the data (write to disk) when `num` of resources are all available (write larger size of data is faster). Therefore, for example, if less than  `num`  of resources are separately locked, I then may have to release (just after I lock) them for next time because the rests are still not available even timeout passes. I think it is a poor design. Need helps.

Comment: System V seems to support this kind of semaphore. However, Windows and pthread are not.

Comment: Not sure whether such thing is possible. But better choice would be to use condition-signal machanism. When required number of resources are available, you signal consumer from producer.

Comment: @MayurK Maybe you are right. I think I can achieve that goal in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

After searching online, I think there is **no** simple and offical way to implement a semaphore with multiple locks. System V supports this kind of semaphore, but I think it is awkward to use it on Windows.

Instead, I choice to use condition-signal machanism (based on `pthreads`) as mentioned by @MayurK with one producer (that acquires the data) and one consumer (that stores the data to disk). To make things easier, I implement a buffer handle utility [`Flex-Buffer`](https://github.com/BoshenGuan/Flex-Buffer) and host it on Github. Hope it will help others with similar concerns.